# Restoring personal certificate on windows 10 due to encrypted files

Tags: windows-10, encryption, certificate, efs

I ran into some trouble. In certmgr.msc I have removed my personal certificate by mistake while trying to update some certificates needed for ID card. The problem is that files which were encrypted with EFS are no longer accessible. Is there any procedure how could I restore certificate and upload personal keys which are still on my computer. Or there is any other solution?

Comment: What do you mean by “which are still on my computer“?

Comment: I mean the keys. I did not reinstall the windows or anything so they are still on my laptop. Through recovery i tried to roll back the mistake that i've made and recovered prior this mistake that i've made but the files are still encrypted. I see that there is certificate in personal folder but my guess it's lacking appropriate keys?

Comment: "Is there any procedure how I could restore the certificate and upload personal keys which are still on my computer?" - If you don't have a copy of the certificate, then the files cannot be decrypted, since the files are securely encrypted.  DId you backup your certificate like you were instructed when you enabled EFS?

Comment: I did not backup certificate. However I see personal certificate on certmgr.msc. Maybe it is just lacking personal key?

Comment: "Just lacking private key", if the key is really missing then the EFS encrypted data will remain inaccessible, because the private key is the crucial part of EFS. No key no data. If your computer part of a domain your admins may be able to decrypt the EFS files using EFS recovery agent.

Comment: No it is not part of domain. I did some research and I found some keys C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys and C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Keys. Is there a way how to connect them with the certificate?

Comment: "Is there a way how to connect them with the certificate?" - Those are not the correct keys.  When you removed the keys from the certificate store, the physical files, were deleted.

Comment: But when I check those keys and files when they are created I see the date when I have encrypted those files. Also I was able to restore the computer prior to the when I removed the personal certificate from certificate store. But still I can not access encrypted  files. What else I can do in this case?